# How I can write a .h headerfile C and C++

Tags: c++

MyHeader.h

```
#ifndef __MYHEADER_H
  #define __MYHEADER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C"{
#endif
  void dchar(unsigned char);
  void char*(char c);

#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif
#endif
```

Errors

Declaration syntax error

Ambiguity between dchar(unsigned char) and dchar (char)

The program is on the website.

Comment: 1. What do you mean with "the program is on the website? 2. You have a typo in your programm `extren "C" {` should be `extern "C" {` 3. You forgott # before `#ifndef` and `#endif`

Comment: I bet the error is actually coming out of a  C compiler, and you have two overloaded versions of dchar - which won't work in C of course. Please show us your *actual* code (not some mangled version of it), and the declaration of dchar(char).

Comment: Hallo Friends,

I have put program again with everthing on. I have this way. How I can write a .h headerfiles C and C++. You find the program. Thanks a lot for yours feedback.

Comment: 1 This is the complete program including description.


#include <stdio.h>

void dchar(char c)
{printf ("%d\n",(int)c);}

dchar the function is simple and press the numeric value of the passed to the function sign off.
What do you think can go wrong in such a simple function, especially when there type security is provided.
You can check this by compiling this short source file separately. Then enter the following source and compile it into position.

Comment: 2 This is the complete program including description

include <stdio.h>
include "myheader.h"

extern void dchar (unsigned char);

void main()

{dchar(128);}

Everything seems to be normal until you try to run the linked program. Instead of weathered deed value 128
To resolve this problem by using well-written header files. Write the external declaration in a .h header files and use #include
To add the header file in the program.

Comment: Dear Peter Paul Kiefer en Martin Bonner, I have put the program in two piece: 1 This is the complete program include description and 2 This is the complete program include description.

Answer (score 1):

You are using C linkage in your program, this means names will not be mangled by the compiler. In your example, you declare two functions named `dchar`, one taking an `unsigned char` argument, one taking a `char` argument. Because of the C linkage, these will both appear to the linker using the name `dchar` instead of the usual mangled name. The linker cannot see the difference between these two functions, and will throw an error, since it thinks you implemented the same function twice.

Since you marked this question as C++, you could solve this by simply removing the `extern "C"` declaration, if you want to use these functions in C too, you will need to change the name of one function.

Comment: Dear Shadowwolf, I wont you to see the program caution. Because it is about write an .h-headerfile for the program. The extern "C"has to be uses. Can you write the header file for this program? That is my question now? I have try for two month. please help me.